# How to get records with max value from two columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table structure like below in postgressql
Where one ticketid can have multiple priority and rating

If i want the list of all ticket ids who have max priority as 2 and max rating as 3.
Then output should give t2 and t4

If i want the list of all ticket ids who have max priority as 3 and max rating as 3.
Then output should give t1 only

I am not sure how to write a query for this

[image]

Comment: Your verbal description of what output you expect does not match up with the actual table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` keyword to filter an aggregate after grouping:

```sql
SELECT ticketid 
FROM ratings 
GROUP BY ticketid 
HAVING max(priority) = 2 
AND max(rating) = 3;
 ticketid
----------
 t4
 t2
(2 rows)
```